# How do you pass a block, written in C, to Ruby's rb_mod_refine?

Tags: c, ruby, mri, ruby-native-extensions

Perhaps more generally, how do you pass a block, written in C, to another C function that accepts a block? I know I can do something like this:

```c
VALUE refine_foobar(VALUE block_arg, VALUE data, int argc, VALUE* argv) {
  // block code here
  return Qnil;
}

void Init_mything() {
  VALUE mod = rb_define_module("Foobar");
  rb_block_call(mod, rb_intern("refine"), 0, NULL, refine_foobar, Qnil);
}
```

but I feel like there has to be a way to call `rb_mod_refine` directly instead of going through `rb_block_call`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In a twist of fate, I have realized that `rb_mod_refine` isn't mentioned in the ruby.h header file, so maybe I'm not even supposed to use it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current usage, refinements are applied to modules. It's right there in the method's name.

AFAIK, it does not directly work with blocks.

The only way I can see this working is to create a "C" method in a module and then use ruby code to apply that module as a refinement in the conventional manner.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I follow. Refinements are defined inside modules, but refinements are not themselves modules (at least not from a top-level API point of view). In other words I don't know if it's possible to "apply that module as a refinement." The module, defined in C, could be included inside the block passed to `refine` however. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Refinements change a module with a scope. The include method imports methods from a module. If this is done in a refinement, then a module is being used to apply a changes to another module in that refinement.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up trying, and it worked :) Thank you!